# Solve equation using optim()

Tags: r

I have 2 equation that need to be solved by using optim

```
{(4x^2-20x+1/4 y^2+8=0
  1/2 xy^2+2x-5y+8=0)
```

I have already run the code,but I'm confused if there should be 1 answer or 2 because function will only return the results for the last line

Should I do like this

```
> myfunc=function(x){
+  4*x[1]^2-20*x[1]+(x[2]^2/4)+8
+  }
> optim(c(0,0),myfunc,method="BFGS")
```

and

```
>  myfunc=function(x){
+  (1/2)*(x[1]*x[2]^2)+2*x[1]-5*x[2]+8
+  }
> optim(c(0,0),myfunc,method="BFGS")
```

or should I do like this

```
> myfunc=function(x){
+  4*x[1]^2-20*x[1]+(x[2]^2/4)+8
+  (1/2)*(x[1]*x[2]^2)+2*x[1]-5*x[2]+8
+  }
> optim(c(0,0),myfunc,method="BFGS")
```

For the second one it still give me only the answer for the second function so which method is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Minimize the sum of the squares of the two expressions that should equal zero and ensure that the value at the optimum equals 0 (up to floating point approximation).

```
myfunc <- function(z) {
  x <- z[1]
  y <- z[2]
  (4*x^2-20* x + 1/4*y^2 + 8)^2 + (1/2 * x*y^2 + 2*x- 5*y + 8)^2
}
optim(c(0, 0), myfunc)
```

giving:

```
$par
[1] 0.5000553 2.0002986

$value
[1] 1.291233e-06

$counts
function gradient 
      67       NA 

$convergence
[1] 0

$message
NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a package for solving systems of non linear equations such as `nleqslv`.

Slightly redefine your function by making it return a vector containing the result for each equation

```
myfunc <- function(x){
    y <- numeric(length(x))
    y[1] <- 4*x[1]^2-20*x[1]+(x[2]^2/4)+8
    y[2] <- (1/2)*(x[1]*x[2]^2)+2*x[1]-5*x[2]+8
    y
}
```

Define a starting value for the solver

```
xstart <- c(0,0)
```

Then do this

```
library(nleqslv)
nleqslv(xstart,myfunc)
```

giving

```
$x
[1] 0.5 2.0

$fvec
[1] -1.472252e-09 -7.081979e-10

$termcd
[1] 1

$message
[1] "Function criterion near zero"

$scalex
[1] 1 1

$nfcnt
[1] 7

$njcnt
[1] 1

$iter
[1] 7
```

There are more packages that can solve equation systems such as `BB` and `pracma`.